# Масштабирование svg схемы

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile, адаптивность

Использую некую библиотеку для svg схемы стадиона, сайт по покупке билетов ВТБ Арена, в самой библиотеке не предусмотрен функционал приближение и отдаление на телефоне, а там как раз таки оно оооочень нужно! Есть функции и в целом знаю, как написать код, который приблизит или отдалит при помощи библиотеки, но проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как отследить, что пользователь приблизил или отдалил. **Вопрос в том - как понять, что пользователь захотел приблизить или отдалить на сенсорном телефоне схему и как узнать центр ( то, куда хочет приблизить пользователь ) приближения?** Дайте хотя бы правильное направление.. Может есть какое-то такое событие в js или нужно будет отслеживать одновременные касания на div и что-то такое... В общем голову ломаю...

Answer (score 0):

В общем решением оказалось, что существуют некие тач-события, от них отталкиваться и нужно :)
Вот статейка: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: для начала - можно просто добивать две кнопочки (приблизить/отдалить)